# Hangouts on Air API

Tags: google-api

Estou tentando integrar o Hangout on Air ao meu sistema.
Eu preciso que o usuário administrador possa criar hangouts e os usuários ouvintes possam entrar nessa ala. 
eu consigo criar a sala, porém não consigo retornar a URL do hangout para possa ser disponibilizado para os ouvintes.
Se não fiquei claro, é algo parecido com que o https://www.verbling.com/ faz.

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt. Traduza sua pergunta e coloque exemplo de código para a comunidade lhe ajudar melhor.

Comment: Desculpe, não sabia que existia esse domínio para os brasileiros.

Comment: Tranquilo. Nos mostre o que vc já fez? coloque exemplo de códigos na sua pergunta.

Comment: Na verdade Dener até o momento eu criei o meu app_secret no console do google, e consegui colocar o botão de teste para iniciar o hangout. até ai tudo bem, mas eu preciso pegar essa url que é gerada para poder mostra-la para os usuários entrarem no hangout.
É como se o você pudesse começar uma reunião no meu sistema e o meu sistema disponibilize o link para os usuários participarem.

Comment: De uma olhada aqui no link, talvez encontre a solução https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26056105/find-out-url-of-the-hangout-started-with-hangoutbutton